# REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS Firing but No Prompt

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, notifications, battery

I'm trying to disable battery optimization on Android 9 with `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` in a push notification when the app is launched.

In the activity file (using notification builder):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder...
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

In the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

I'm able to get the push notification to show, but when you tap, it just disappears. The prompt for 'Allow' doesn't pop up. Am I doing something wrong with the setup?

Comment: Check the logcat. Don't filter it or you might miss something important. You could also try changing the `Intent` to open some other app that doesn't require permissions and see if that works (just to narrow down the problem)

Comment: Is this still a recommended permission by Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Uri in the data. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS):

> Input: The Intent's data URI must specify the application package name
>   to be shown, with the "package" scheme. That is "package:com.my.app".

Do something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
intent.setData(Uri.parseString("package:my.package.name");
```